# Is there any React Native Date Range picker with date blocking

Tags: react-native, daterangepicker

I am building a booking system using react native, but I am not able to find a Date Range Picker that enables me to block the reserved dates as shown in the following picture.

[blocking dates on a calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrWfp.jpg)

Is there any component that does this job ??
I would preferer functional component if there is any

Answer (score 0):

Try [react-native-calendars](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars).

Usage:

```js
const school = {key:'school', color: 'orange', selectedDotColor: 'blue'};
const canteen = {key:'canteen', color: 'blue', selectedDotColor: 'blue'};
const rooms = {key:'rooms', color: 'green'};

<Calendar
  markedDates={{
    '2017-10-25': {dots: [school, canteen, rooms], selected: true, selectedColor: 'red'},
    '2017-10-26': {dots: [canteen, rooms], disabled: true}
  }}
  markingType={'multi-dot'}
/>
```

Comment: I really liked this library, but unfortunately it is not a range picker  :(